# How to make MySQL log down all queries that didn't use index?

Tags: sql, mysql, logging

I'm starting to do the job of sql optimization,

but I don't know how to configure MySQL properly to make it log slow queries.

Answer (score 1):

This link might be to some help:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html